# Searching for Fields of Subform - MS Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, subform

Suppose i have Mainform and Subform as show in this image.
Now i trying to serching for SubformID=6 when i am on 
MainformID=2 and if i found SubformID=6 then i wish to goto that perticular MainformID (e.g.MainformID=1).

[Download Sample Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4VKVJp2vo33XzZtNU5VR2dOOTA/view?usp=sharing)

Using find and replace it couldn't be done.

please suggest me proper way
[image]
i have also read [this thread](http://www.accessforums.net/forms/search-subform-goto-%20%20record-main-form-21306.html) but can't getting it.

i am looking for something nice solution for this.

Comment: your subform results are always filtered according to your main form id. you would not find the subformID 6 when your result set does not have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to flesh-out gustav's answer a bit more, I'd add a search field and button to your form so you can move to the record using some controls.

[image]

[Here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-J5B7nFljZiRFVMNEV4RG5raUE/view?usp=sharing) your file back with the changes; have a look at the on-click event of the search button I've added, which has the following code (basically what gustav has already supplied):

```vb
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()

    Dim MainFK As Long

    MainFK = DLookup("MainformID", "Subform", "SubformID =" & Me.txtSearch)

    DoCmd.SearchForRecord acDataForm, "MainForm", acFirst, "MainformID=" & MainFK

End Sub
```

Thank you for providing a screenshot - that made it clear what you were after :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use DLookup:

```
Dim SearchedId As Long
SearchedId = 6
MainformId = DLookup("MainformID", "Subform", "SubformID = " & SearchedId & "")
```

Then you can use DoCmd.SearchForRecord to position the mainform at MainformId.